# Is groups or containers draggable in phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

i am new in phaser development trying to drag a sprite with a text above it but it seems that neither groups nor containers helped me
any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups are really just glorified Arrays, they are not Game Objects, so you can't drag one. A Container, however, you definitely can. You would need to pass in a hit area for it to use, as they don't have a size by default, so it can't make one automatically. But once it has a hit area, drags on that area would work fine.

[This example](http://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Cgame%20objects%5Ccontainer%5Cdraggable%20container.js) shows how to create a draggable Container. Click the Edit button to see the source.